# Why does TortoiseSVN not seem to recognize my Powershell scripts as text files?

Tags: powershell, tortoisesvn

I'm using TortoiseSVN (version 1.7.10, Build 23359) to store my Powershell scripts in Subversion (1.7.7) but when I try to view the "diff with previous version", I see a file with "þ" in the first line, the rest blank and some of the blank lines marked different. It seems that SVN is seeing my Powershell file as a binary file rather than text. Is there some encoding change I can make so that TortoiseSVN recognizes it?

Comment: You may need to save your PowerShell script files as plain ASCII (ANSI) rather than UTF-8 or UNICODE.

Comment: Bill is correct--it is all about the editor you are using to save your scripts; it has nothing to do with TortoiseSVN per se.

Answer (score 0):

I found [someone else having the same problem](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/winserverpowershell/thread/dacb75cb-47da-4120-8dca-c697f8a84c70/) and it looks like Powershell ISE (v2.0) uses Unicode Big Endian instead of UTF8. I can edit my files in another editor, use Powershell v3 (that uses UTF8 by default they say - unconfirmed) or use a tool like [KDIFF](http://kdiff3.sourceforge.net/) that supports unicode.